# std::thread in constructor referencing it's deleted copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, move

I'm having a surprising amount of trouble with a constructor I'm writing.  It's something incrediably basic, but I'm having a bad day because I'm totally stumped.

```cpp
class RenderThread {
public:
    RenderThread(std::thread && threadToGive) 
        : m_renderThread(threadToGive) {}

private:
    std::thread m_renderThread;
};


int test() {
    std::thread thread;
    RenderThread rt(std::move(thread));
}
```

My constructor is trying to call `std::thread::thread(const std::thread &)` which is definitely not my goal, even if it was possible.  I want to move the argument `threadToGive` into `m_renderThread`, not copy it.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `RenderThread(std::thread && threadToGive) : m_renderThread(std::move(threadToGive)) {}`.

Comment: @songyuanyao - oh jeez that's it.  I thought using `std::move` on an object of `Type &&` was redundant, but I guess I was wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: `threadToGive` is an lvalue itself, even its type is rvalue-reference. Value category and type are two independent properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `std::move()` the `RenderThread` constructor's parameter into the constructor of the `m_renderThread` member:

```
   : m_renderThread(std::move(threadToGive)) {}
```